# How to change the color of the artboard in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, document-setup

It is practically impossible to edit a white illustration on the default white artboard background.

Hiding the artboard makes the whole work area receive the artboard's white color.

So, is there a way to change the color of the artboard in Illustrator CC?

Comment: I would also like to know if there's a way to do this. In the meantime what I do is make a rectangle or square shape that covers the artboard's dimensions, fill with the colour I want for background and lock it so I can work over it.

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18166/change-background-color-of-just-one-artboard-in-illustrator-cs5?rq=1

Comment: Change your Grid preferences to have black gridlines every 1 pixel. It's not perfect but it works.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The easiest way to see white artwork in Illustrator is by opening the **View Menu** and selecting **Show Transparency Grid**. This gives your white artwork something to contrast with. You can adjust the color of the grid by going to 'File → Document Setup'.

Comment: This is it! After about two years, this is the one answer that seems to actually work. For anybody reading, note that you can set the both grid colors, so picking, for example, grey and grey checkers will give you a solid grey background when turning transparency grid on. Bravo!

Comment: This works great, but just for the record - it's total C R A P that Adobe doesn't give us an explicit way to do this - that doesn't involve changing these types or settings or an extra layer. It would probably take them 15 minutes to program this option.

Answer (score 44):

You can "tweak" the artboard color by this way:

Select <kbd>File</kbd>-><kbd>Document Setup...</kbd>

On the popup window you will have Transparency sub-menu:

[image]

Choose the upper color (I set it to rose) and Mark "Simulate Colored Paper" -

You will get this image -

[image]

There is no any other layers except of text ones...

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help with this question, which is how to make *white* visible. White text will disappear against the artboard, regardless of its color.

Comment: @alangilbertson i dont delete the answer because of your very interesting comment

Comment: No, Alan, the question is "Is there a way to change the color of the artboard in Illustrator CC?" It's in bold. You can read it for yourself. White is used as an example. And White is not white. There's CMYK white (absence of ink) and HSB and RGB White (Additive Blended Light becomes white). In the case of HSB and RGB, they'll be clearly visible on a coloured artBoard. But Adobe doesn't provide this because they're... lazy?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is pretty nifty otherwise, but as mentioned I have a problem editing white vectors, so this approach does not remedy that.

Comment: This may have been obvious to others, but the help I needed was both the above, and the information to go to "View->Turn On Transparency Grid" -- then, you can darken the transparency grid with the above and white becomes evident enough to work with.

Comment: Personally, when working with white objects and transparency I'll use the transparency grid rather than simulating colored paper (maybe add a bit about how to enable the transparency grid?). Good answer.

Comment: @Ilan I have no idea if you will see this message, but if you see can you tell me where I can find the artwork of your thumbnail profile picture, any artist name or any place where I can see or buy, would be much appreciated. thanks (I will delete this message after you answer or if no response in few days)

Comment: @Ilan actually just printing for house decoration (personal use)

Comment: In the transparency grid, why can't we have both colors (Rose and beige in your case) same?

Answer (score 15):

There's no simple way that I know of.

You can, however, create a rectangle of the same dimensions as the artboard, change its colour to one that works better, move it to the back (<kbd>Command/Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>) - or even to a lower layer and make the layer a template layer, so that it isn't included in the export.

It's not a perfect solution, I know, but it works for me.

Comment: Surprisingly, "Arrange > Send to Back" didn't work for me. I needed to go to "Window > Layers" and then drag a layer down manually.

Comment: This worked fine--except for [a bug in Illustrator](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2217092) where template layers still export for PNG files!

Answer (score 12):

The short answer is no, you can't, but there is a reason for that which becomes apparent the moment you look at a CMYK "white" swatch. It's 0% everything: no ink.

White, to Illustrator, is not a color or a mixture of colors, it is an *absence* of ink. Even if you're working with an RGB document, that's still the way Illustrator thinks about color: white = absence.

When setting a layout to be printed with white pigment, such as for screen printing on clothing, or product labels that are printed directly onto glass or plastic, the artwork is usually submitted as black or a faux spot color with instructions to print using white. It's similar to the way that spot varnish is specified on a layout. The important thing is that it will separate on its own plate, not what color it appears to be on the screen.

That's why ilan's solution won't work for you. If you simulate colored paper, then anything white will *still* disappear, because that's how Illustrator shows you that the paper will show through -- there's no pigment.

Your two solutions are to put a colored rectangle on a non-printing layer beneath your artwork, or temporarily change all your white fills or strokes to something visible for editing purposes, then change it back when you're ready to save.

Comment: The parts here about color handling aren't quite correct. Illustrator **isn't** a print-specific product and will define and treat white as a color (see the behavior during an export to `.png`). The mapping of white to "paper color" is typically handled in pre-press (via InDesign or similar). The CMYK white swatch is 0%, yes, but that is only because of how the CMYK colorspace works.

Comment: To add to Alan's answer, if you also set the non-printing background layer to "Template" then if you "Save for Web" it won't include it in the export.

Comment: Yes but Illustrator isn't only used for printing. You can use it also to create assets for animations or graphics for a computer game.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best solution to work with white artwork/artwork that doesn't contrast well is to create a separate layer and add a fill.

Then double-click the layer in the Layers Panel and uncheck the "Print" checkbox. This allows you to edit the artwork whenever you need and that layer will NEVER print.

You can place it in another document in any Adobe software and it will not show layers with print unchecked.

Comment: This was enlightening, but when creating SVG for web use, the 'print' option doesn't leave out that part of the SVG in the code.

Comment: Sorry this is 6 years later! I'm sure there are use cases where it doesn't behave properly such as SVG. I've had issues with SVGs slightly modifying my perfect shapes, so I usually try to keep an AI version that I save to SVG rather than rely on being able to edit SVGs in Illustrator.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a box the size you need in pixels the color you want in Illustrator and put it behind your logo and save that and you should get what you need.

Comment: Which makes object selection hell..

Comment: Throw it on the bottom layer and lock it up?

Answer (score 3):

**Step-1**": First create your art-board and set the height width and resolution according to your requirements.

**Step-2**
then go to FIle > then Click Document setup

[image]

Step-3

Check the button **Simulate Colored Paper**

[image]

and then click on the color from the color chart ( basic color section or color table section) to choose your desired art background color

[image]

Then hit ok Then again ok

Here you go 
[image]

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this, like I did, and wonders where the color selector is:
It is the topmost one in the transparency section (adjacent to "grid size"). I found that to be far from intuitive.

Comment: For me, this only seems to work if not using "View > Show Transparency Grid".

Comment: That's a great technique! I love learning new things.