# Is there a way to make Adobe Illustrator's artboard with specific color?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to make Adobe Illustrator's artboard with specific color whenever open new document with out making a path?

I have been searching the entire illustrator settings for this, but didn't found what I'm looking for.

Thank you :)

Comment: Might be helpful, not sure you can do this automatically... https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/31053/63979

Comment: It's important to know **why** you want to do this. It's not standard and unless you are familiar with Illustrator, playing with the transparency grid settings can be problematic. And "simulate colored stock" can be fraught with issues if you don't understand how it alters some previews (like white). -- But there *are* ways to have every new document open with a layer containing a colored rectangle by default.

Comment: It's work but when trying to export, the result still white background

Comment: @Scott When I designed the logo, lets say designing a pictoral logo of a skull. It's become so time consuming when design the logo with deffault white background, when logo is done, and apply on dark background, the color of the logo is need to be inverted right? the logo become awkward. The strange thing is when designing something pictoral logo with dark background from the begining, the logo always works on different background color.

Comment: Quite honestly, the *simplest and easiest* solution is to just draw a rectangle filled with color, clock it.. then continue working. Altering the file set up swill create *more* work when you *don't* want a colored background.

Comment: Howabout an action to make the background square

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't edit the artboard color directly.

Other options include:

- Create a template layer that contains a rectangle filled with the desired color. https://www.agitraining.com/adobe/illustrator/tutorials/template-layers-in-illustrator
- Enabling the transparency grid via Illustrator >> View >> Show transparency grid

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

1. Draw a rectangle to fit the artboard and fill it black, and set the stroke to none.
2. In the Layers panel, lock the layer, and then create a new layer.
3. Do *File > Save As*, and save the file as an AIT (Adobe Illustrator Template).
4. Any time you want to use it, just double click the AIT file to launch Illustrator.